# Set SelectedIndex of combobox to an index found by a key value in the underlying DataSource?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, datatable, selectedindex

The DataSource of comboBox is a DataTable. The DataTable has a key column called ID, the values of IDs can be 1,2,3,4,5.

I want to set the SelectedIndex of comboBox correspondingly to the ID I want. Here is my try, it works OK but I'm not sure it's the best:

```
DataTable source = (DataTable) myComboBox.DataSource;
DataRow[] rows = source.Select(string.Format("ID='{0}'", 3));//the ID I want is 3
myComboBox.SelectedIndex = rows.Length == 0 ? -1 : source.Rows.IndexOf(rows[0]);
```

Do you have another better solution?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your current solution seems fine, why do you want to change it ?

Comment: @Habib No, I'm using it, I'm just a little curious if there is a better solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried myself, but I'm not sure if they are better than the one I posted in my original question. Here they are:

1. Use the `Find()` method of `BindingSource`:

   ```
   //Only 1 line of code, seems to much cleaner :)
   myComboBox.SelectedIndex = new BindingSource(myComboBox.DataSource,"").Find("ID",3);
   //In fact, I thought of this before but I had tried the solution in my OP first.
   ```
2. Use a little trick with `FindStringExact()` method of `ComboBox`:

   ```
   string currentDisplayMember = myComboBox.DisplayMember;
   myComboBox.DisplayMember = "ID";
   myComboBox.SelectedIndex = myComboBox.FindStringExact("3");
   myComboBox.DisplayMember = currentDisplayMember;
   ```

The #2 should be used carefully if you have something related to `DisplayMember` to handle when the `SelectedIndexChanged` is fired.

I hope this helps others. Please leave your comment below if they're better than the method I used in my original question. Thanks!